# How do I loop this using jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops

I am not lying I am a beginner. So here is my issue. I am receiving a json object in an ajax request and would like to loop its content. I need to create the loop and gather data within the variable "pins."

```
function(data) {

                   var pins = [
                                   {
                                        "lat":      data.lat,
                                        "lon":      data.lon,
                                        "imageURL": data.imageURL,
                                        "title":    data.title,
                                        "subTitle": data.subTitle,
                                        "pinColor": data.pinColor,
                                        "selected": data.selected,
                                        "pinImage": data.pinImage,
                                        "index":    data.index
                                    }
                               ];
         }
```

Data is an object and I would like to loop every single element using jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: I am data from a json object in an Ajax request. 

... success: function(data) {} etc.

Comment: Are you looking to loop over data to generate pins or looking to loop over pins?

Comment: If so, is data an array of objects that each have these attributes?

Comment: Yes data is the json object with all the pins. And I need to loop within my object. I need the brakets otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: What are you talking about? `{` and `}` means it contains an object and `[` and `]` means it contains an array. Hence `pins` is an array of objects.

Comment: Can you give an example of what `data` looks like? If `data` has the same structure that you're looking for, then as @h2ooooooo suggested, you can simply set `pins` equal to `data`. I'm guessing `data` has more than you're looking to get though?

Answer (score 1):

This is a javascript array with an object inside, and has nothing to do with jQuery (nor should you use jQuery to loop through it).

```
for (var i = 0; i < pins.length; i++) {
    console.log(pins[i].lat);
    console.log(pins[i].lon);
    console.log(pins[i].imageURL);
    //etc
}
```

Comment: He can use jQuery, if he wants.

Comment: jQuery provides convenience methods to loop through objects, so there's no reason not to use them aside from the performance impact.

Comment: Your answer does not work. I would like a full answer where the brakets are kept since I need them to create a pin. Something like var pins = [ $.each etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each({ a: 1, b: 2}, function(key, value){
    console.log(key, value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work to iterate over `data` to collect the desired attributes from each object in the array and construct `pins`.

```
function(data) {
    var pins = [];

    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var new_pin = {
            "lat":      data[i].lat,
            "lon":      data[i].lon,
            "imageURL": data[i].imageURL,
            "title":    data[i].title,
            "subTitle": data[i].subTitle,
            "pinColor": data[i].pinColor,
            "selected": data[i].selected,
            "pinImage": data[i].pinImage,
            "index":    data[i].index
        };

        pins.push(new_pin);
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is the case, what *exactly* would be the difference between this and `var pins = data;`?

Comment: There would only be a difference if the OP doesn't want to collect all of the attributes... I don't exactly know what the OP is desiring here. Perhaps `data` isn't structured quite this simply.

Comment: If that is the case, then it may very well be functionally equivalent to setting `var pins = data` as h2ooooooo said. @user2415277, if you believe this answer is the solution, please accept it as such. Thank you.